# Catching errors in rxjs with mergeMap operator

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, mergemap

I've written a code in which I would like to catch an error when exception occurs:

```
this.assetApiService.getAssets(new AssetSearchCriteriaDto({tags: [AssetTags.tenant]})).pipe(
          catchError(error => {
           console.log(error);
          }),
          (mergeMap((assets: AssetDto[]) => {
                this.appInitStorageService.setAvailableTenants(assets);
                return this.userApiService.getUserById(this.authApiService.getAuth().userInfo.id);
              }
            )
          )
        )
          .subscribe((user: UserDto) => {
            this.persistSelectedUserLanguage(user);
            this.appInitStorageService.setUser(user);
            resolve();
          }, error => {
            console.log('error:', error);
          });
```

The goal is to catch errors either if they occur from first observable in sequence(getAssets) or in second observable(getUserById). I've added catchError operator in first one but I can't see console.log(error). I don't know why. How should I properly catch errors in this example?

Answer (score 0):

You could just move the `catchError` below the `mergeMap` to catch errors from both the observables. Also very important to remember that `catchError` **must** return an observable. You could use RxJS [`throwError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/throwError) function to throw an error observable

```js
this.assetApiService.getAssets(new AssetSearchCriteriaDto({tags: [AssetTags.tenant]})).pipe(
  mergeMap((assets: AssetDto[]) => {
    this.appInitStorageService.setAvailableTenants(assets);
    return this.userApiService.getUserById(this.authApiService.getAuth().userInfo.id);
  }),
  catchError(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return throwError(error); // return error that will trigger the subscriptions `error` block
  })
).subscribe({
  next: (user: UserDto) => {
    this.persistSelectedUserLanguage(user);
    this.appInitStorageService.setUser(user);
    resolve();
  }, 
  error: error => {
    console.log('error:', error);
  }
});
```

If you on the other hand wish to convert errors to valid emissions and consequently keep the stream running instead of erroring out, you could use RxJS [`of`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/of) function. The the errors will be emitted to the subscription's `next` callback instead of `error` callback

```js
this.assetApiService.getAssets(new AssetSearchCriteriaDto({tags: [AssetTags.tenant]})).pipe(
  mergeMap((assets: AssetDto[]) => {
    this.appInitStorageService.setAvailableTenants(assets);
    return this.userApiService.getUserById(this.authApiService.getAuth().userInfo.id);
  }),
  catchError(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return of(error); // return error that will trigger the subscriptions `next` block
  })
).subscribe({...});
```

Comment: I've changed order of operators but I still can't see console log. Don't you know why?

Comment: Do you mean the `console.log` inside `catchError` or the subscription?

Comment: Yes. I can't see it.

Comment: That isn't a yes/no question? Which `console.log` do you mean?

Comment: I mean this part: catchError(error => {
            console.log("error", error);
            return of(error); // return error that will trigger the subscriptions `next` block
          })

Comment: In that case the observables isn't emitting an error. `catchError` will only be triggered when the observable emits an error. Note: observable error is not the same as an HTTP error. An HTTP request may emit an error message as a valid notification in the observable.

Comment: Ok. Should I add catching error inside http Observable? I can see also there pipe method: return this.sharedService.httpGetWithPagination<Asset>(
      this.sharedService.buildApiUrl('assets'),
      this.assetMapperService.assetSearchCriteriaDtoToAssetSearchCriteria(assetSearchCriteriaDto),
      withFurtherPages,
    ).pipe(
      map((assets: Asset[]) => this.assetMapperService.assetArrayToAssetDtoArray(assets)),
      reduce((all: AssetDto[], current: AssetDto[]) => all.concat(current)),
    );

Comment: No there is no difference in adding `catchError` in the `mergerMap` or the HTTP request. You need to make sure the HTTP request in itself throws an error instead of a valid response. Or if you wish to do it instead in the frontend, you need to catch the response using `switchMap` and throw error using `throwError` function. This is inelegant, but will work.

Comment: Yes I know. I received 401 error in browser. I've intentionally changed value of JWT token in order to receive an error.

Answer (score 0):

Is your code compiling? You have to return an Observable in `catchError`:

```
catchError(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return of([ ]);
}),
```

This way the stream can continue processing after the error was caught. As you see `catchError` only makes sense if you can restore the control flow - otherwise the error can bubble up to the subscribe error handler. A big difference is here that the observable stops emitting if an error reaches subscribe, while with `catchError` it will continue emitting (this is not relevant in your case but would be e.g. in case of an `interval` or `fromEvent` Observable that emits multiple values).

If that doesn't solve your issue, make sure that `this.assetApiService.getAssets` actually throws an exception. Maybe it just returns a response with an error response code for some reason?

Comment: _"`catchError` only makes sense if you can restore the control flow"_ - that is debatable. In a stream with multiple observables, I could handle errors from each observable individually. But that doesn't mean the flow has to be restored. I could return the error out with `throwError` that could be caught by the more generic error handling in the subscription. Simply put, it depends on the use-case. In some cases the stream needs to be stopped after handling the error and in some cases it doesn't necessarily need to be.

Comment: One other common use case is error handling + `retry`/`retryWhen`. The `catchError` is used to handle the error and emitting the error again using `throwError` ensures the stream is *restarted* using `retry` or `retryWhen` operator.